# How can I use the (seemingly built in) famo.us device view?

Tags: famo.us

In [this launch event](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16K6DOLAmUM&t=3m42s), Hongxu Liu adds device views to his famous app. Are they open sourced? I cannot find anything about it. I am currently developing a phonegap app, and this would come in handy.

Comment: How would this become handy for a phonegap app? Are you going to draw a cellphone inside the cellphone? Or are you planning on using it in your desktop browser for debug purposes? If so, there are much better options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer if all you need is to display your famo.us view in the browser.... You could probably do this on your own by finding some generic phone graphics and using famo.us to render the picture, and place your view inside the empty space in the middle of that graphic.

Here's an answer regarding the actual DeviceView answered in another thread too: [famo.us: Can I use "DeviceView" in my own app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452032/famo-us-can-i-use-deviceview-in-my-own-app)